# KEEP Duplicate rows based on cells

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Trying to search an entire range, and delete everything that doesn't have a duplication in Column B.

Trying the following code

```
    lastrow = logSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For r = 2 To lastrow
        If logSheet.Cells(r, 2).Value <> logSheet.Cells(r + 1, 2).Value Or logSheet.Cells(r, 2).Value <> logSheet.Cells(r - 1, 2).Value Then
            logSheet.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
```

The above is only keeping one of the duplications, not both.

I'm sure its something simple that I'm missing, but I just keep brain farting!

Comment: When you delete a row the numbers of subsequent rows change. Therefore you must start your search from the bottom so that when you delete the last row the change in row numbers below doesn't affect the working of your macro.

Comment: Ah, of course! I totally skimmed over that!

Edit: Just chucked the step -1 into it, and now it deletes everything!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to check if there is a duplicate in the next row. That differs from your description where you say nothing about the location of the duplicate. The code below will detect duplicates anywhere in the column and delete items that have none. It should work for your scenario as well as the one I envision.

```
Sub DeleteSingles()
    ' 308

    Dim Rng     As Range
    Dim R       As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With LogSheet
        R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(R, 1))
        For R = R To 2 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, .Cells(R, 1).Value) = 1 Then
                .Rows(R).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My approach to checking for duplicates appears simpler than yours. Besides that, my code works from the bottom up because of the deletions.